# java script command line argument & map

Tags: javascript, command-line, dictionary

I can't find in js how to find how many arguments where sent to the program (line in vb there is numberArg = WScript.Arguments.Count).

In addition I can't find a data structure like a map in js.

I searched the net and could n't find it.

Thanks

Comment: why is this tagged as a "java" question ??

Comment: this was tagged to java script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in java script it is: `WScript.Arguments.length`.

Data structure like map is Object:

```
var map = new Object();
map["hello"] = "world";
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find it in the net. Can u send me a link where u found it ? ot a good link to java script ?

Answer (score 1):

Arguments.length is a size  of array. Also look here for more cool stuff http://nilleb.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/javascript-code-to-use-wscript-parameters/

map is any object.  E.g.

```
var mymap = {a:42, b:"hello world"}
alert(mymap.a)
alert(mymap['b'])
```